# How can I add more pages in report?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have to generate a letter with parameters, and it has 4 pages.

How can I add more than one page in iReport Designer 5.5.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding other 3 detail bands. You have just to click on the `Detail 1` (default) band and click `Add Another Detail Band`. After each band you can insert a `Page Break` component (in your Palette it will be shown simply as `Break`. Once you drop it on the page it will promt to select between Page or Column) :

```
<break>
<reportElement uuid="84b54a9b-244e-4262-a990-8b41e53ced05" x="0" y="15" width="100" height="1"/>
</break>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your data part in `Detail 1` band.
See below example template :

[image]

Here I have define my fields in `Detail 1` band. I hope it is helpful to you.

Comment: you can also use Sub-reports if you need to change things like page Orientation